# Continuous function on $[0,1]$ has at least two zeroes

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous  function on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx = \int_0^1xf(x)\,dx =0$. Show that  there exist $a<b$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

Comment: The language in which this question is phrase is the sort of thing that's appropriate in homework questions or exam questions, and not so much if you're asking us a question in an internet forum.  This makes it look as if you're passing on to us a question written by someone else rather than your own question.

Comment: To counterbalance the unfortunate feeling @MichaelHardy is referring to and to help people adapt their answers, you might wish to add your personal thoughts about this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality assume $f\neq 0$.
Since $\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$, $f(x)$ can neither be strictly positive nor strictly negative on $[0,1]$, hence $f$ has at least one zero.

Suppose then that $f$ has only one zero, at $a$, and that $f(x)<0$ for $x<a$ and $f(x)>0$ for $x>a$ (this can always be accomplished by switching to $-f$ if necessary).
Now
$$\int_0^1(x-a)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x-a\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 0$$
by assumption.
However, $(x-a)f(x)$ is strictly positive except at $a$, a contradiction.
Hence, $f$ has at least two zeroes.